# How to print keys of trie with keys of UTF-8 bytes in Java 8

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a trie where the keys are UTF-8 byte sequences.
I want to print all of the keys, or convert them all to Strings.
I traverse the trie recursively, adding or removing the bytes in an ArrayList.

1. Should I use something other than ArrayList? I want it to be efficient. ByteBuffer?
2. If I do use ArrayList, how do I convert it back to a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The most efficient is likely a large enough `byte[]` that can hold the longest key so you never have to resize it. `ArrayList<Byte>` is pretty terrible because of lots of boxed `Byte`s. `ByteBuffer` works but does not provide much benefit over a raw `byte[]`. A `StringBuilder` could also work but I don't know how well you could remove bytes from one.

2) `System.out.println(new String(bytes, 0, len, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))` where `byte[] bytes` is the byte array and `len` is how many of the bytes you need.

If you really want to use an `ArrayList<Byte>` you can convert like

```
ArrayList<Byte> byteList = ...
byte[] bytes = new byte[byteList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < byteList.size(); i++)
    bytes[i] = byteList.get(i);
System.out.println(new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```